# No summary report produced with Taurus when property in filename

Tags: jmeter, taurus

We have a JMeter test plan with some tests and a Summary Report listener. This JMeter test plan is driven with Taurus from a Azure deployment agent. When we use a JMeter property in the filename of a Summary Report, no report is produced. Like:

[image]

When we add a absolute url, the report IS produced:

[image]

When I run the test plan from the command line WITH the JMeter property in the filename and I provide the property via the command line it does work!

When I look in the jmeter.log, there is no trace of using a Summary Report listener, so no feedback provided from the log.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to mention 2 things:

1. How exactly you're executing your JMeter script "with Taurus", in particular how you're providing this `AGENTDIRECTORY` property. For example I cannot reproduce your issue running a JMeter test via Taurus like:

   ```
   bzt -o modules.jmeter.properties.AGENTDIRECTORY=c:/temp sometest.jmx
   ```

   More information: [JMeter Properties and Variables](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#JMeter-Properties-and-Variables)
2. Why do you need this listener at all, Taurus provides [`kpi.jtl` file](https://gettaurus.org/docs/ArtifactsDir/#Common-files) which can be opened in any [Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html), moreover [having Listeners added to test plan and enabled for anything but test development and/or debugging is a performance anti-pattern](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/greedy-listeners-memory-leeches-performance-testing) so ideally you should not use Listeners at all during the load test execution.

Comment: 1. interesting yes, your comment brought me the idea to also test with the bzt commandline, thnx!

2. To get the results in Azure DevOps test plan I followed this article to help me: https://ganeshsirsi.medium.com/configuring-jmeter-tests-in-vsts-tfs-azure-devops-and-publishing-results-dcdd7b451cb9. In our project we use jmeter for testing the performance of our nightly environment. Do you have any other tutorial to bring the results to Azure DevOps test plans?